# MiKTeX can't convert jupyter notebook to pdf if it contains a markdown image from a website

Tags: pdf, miktex, compiling

I've been having this problem for a long time, and I don't know what else I can do about it.

On Jupyter Notebook, you can add images from the web on markdown cells, through this simple command:

```
![any text](image url)
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Whenever I try to export this notebook as pdf, I get errors.

This is the error I get when I try it through Jupyter Lab:

```
nbconvert failed: PDF creating failed, captured latex output:
Failed to run "xelatex notebook.tex -quiet" command:
notebook.tex:408: Unable to load picture or PDF file '
dvipdfmx:fatal: Image inclusion failed for "https://i.imgur.com/MQdEUrY.png".

No output PDF file written.

Sorry, but xelatex did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

C:\Users\Caique\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\xelatex.log
```

This is the "FATAL" text on the log file:

```
2021-03-10 19:22:12,105-0300 FATAL xelatex.core - Invalid argument
2021-03-10 19:22:12,105-0300 FATAL xelatex.core - Function: fwrite
2021-03-10 19:22:12,105-0300 FATAL xelatex.core - Result: 22
2021-03-10 19:22:12,105-0300 FATAL xelatex.core - Data: <no data>
2021-03-10 19:22:12,105-0300 FATAL xelatex.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\include\miktex/C4P/C4P.h:646
2021-03-10 19:22:12,105-0300 FATAL xelatex - Invalid argument
2021-03-10 19:22:12,105-0300 FATAL xelatex - Info: 
2021-03-10 19:22:12,105-0300 FATAL xelatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\include\miktex/C4P/C4P.h
2021-03-10 19:22:12,105-0300 FATAL xelatex - Line: 646
2021-03-10 19:22:12,107-0300 INFO  xelatex - this process (7532) finishes with exit code 1
```

And finally, when I export it as LaTeX and try to compile it with MiKTeX (using the "pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX" compiler), I get this error:

```
LaTeX Warning: File `https://i.imgur.com/MQdEUrY.png' not found on input line 408.

! Package pdftex.def Error: File `https://i.imgur.com/MQdEUrY.png' not found: using draft setting.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                              
l.408 ...raphics{https://i.imgur.com/MQdEUrY.png}
                                              
?
```

Note that those errors are related to another notebook (thus, another image), but this kind of error happens everytime the notebook has in image from a website.

**Does anyone know how I can fix this?**

Comment: well neither pdflatex nor dvipdfmx can download images from a remote location. You will have to change the link to a local reference.